# Hosting ServiceStack using Windows Azure worker role

Tags: azure, servicestack, azure-worker-roles

I am new to Windows Azure Cloud Services. I want to host a service, built using ServiceStack, on a worker role. I have tried a few ways including the following one but no success.

Code I have tried:

```cs
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public AppHost()
            : base("HttpListener Self-Host", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            Routes
            .Add<Hello>("/hello")
            .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name}");
        }
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.       

        try
        {
            var endpoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["Endpoint1"];
            string baseUri = string.Format("{0}://{1}/", endpoint.Protocol, endpoint.IPEndpoint);

            var appHost = new AppHost();
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start(baseUri);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Could not start service host. {0}", e.Message);
        }

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

Service is deployed successfully but I am unable to access the service.

Comment: So what is the exception?

Comment: You might want to watch [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Cloud-Services-Tutorials/Introduction-to-Windows-Azure-Worker-Roles-Part-1). While it's not ServiceStack the principals are the same. Ensure that you have configured your endpoint access correctly.

Comment: Did you check the operational logs? are there any errors?

Comment: Actually the app host is being started and no exception is being thrown while starting app host. I printed out the IP Endpoint of worker role in trace and used that to send request browser cant find that. Although if i run this project on local machine it works fine. I followed following links for ServiceStack self-hosting and deploying API on worker role:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/host-aspnet-web-api-in-an-azure-worker-role

Comment: Haider - did you ever get this working? I'm looking at doing something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running it with elevated priviledges? In order to open an HTTP port you need to run as an administrator. You can do this by adding `<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />` to your worker role in the service definition.

Alternatively you could make a startup script (which of course has to run in elevated mode) to [run a netsh command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725882%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_4) allowing you to open the ports without elevated priviledges.

Comment: It didn't work. Please see my comments under the question post.